# Getting hostname of URL in loop - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse, hostname, http-response-codes

So I'm currently trying to make an http status code checker. But for some reason the response hostname is returning undefined, yet i can retrieve the response statusCode. Am I grabbing it properly?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener('data', function (userInput) {
    var urlListPath = userInput.toString().trim();
    fs.readFile(urlListPath, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    var urlArray = data.toString().split("\n");
        urlArray =  urlArray.filter(Boolean);

        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){
            http.get({hostname: urlArray[i]}, function(res){
                console.log(res.hostname + ' | ' + res.statusCode + ' | ' + res.statusMessage);
            });
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: Put it in a function with url as a parameter

Comment: hmm... why would that make a difference? Each iteration is getting a new object passed to http.get, and the value is being copied from the array to said object on each iteration,

Comment: Ah, i see, you're not getting the host from the res anymore, you're grabbing it from the original object. so you just worked around the problem, that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by wrapping in a function as @bluesman suggested:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener('data', function (userInput) {
    var urlListPath = userInput.toString().trim();
    fs.readFile(urlListPath, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    var urlArray = data.toString().split("\n");
        urlArray =  urlArray.filter(Boolean);

        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){
            getHttpInfo(urlArray[i]);
        }
  });
});

function getHttpInfo(url){
    http.get({hostname: url}, function(res){
        console.log(url + ' : ' + res.statusCode + ' | ' + res.statusMessage);
    });
}
```